# Phonegap - Adding header to WebView - jQuery Mobile

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

I am developing a Phonegap App for iOS and Android. I am using jQuery Mobile and its pages to create the app and navigation. All pages have a header with a back button.

```
<div data-role="header"  data-position="fixed" data-add-back-btn="true">
```

Now, some links don't link to pages but to regular websites which are opened in the Phonegap WebView. Although this WebView is a fullscreen browser with no header bar. So once a user opened a link in the WebView there is no way of going back (or at least it's difficult). I would like to add the same header bar from my other pages to the WebView. Is that possible?

Comment: Use the inappbrowser, there you have a back button.

Comment: please comment on the negative vote

Answer (score 0):

As Joerg suggests use the [InAppBrowser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser) is a plugin.

Make sure you read about the whitelist. It is #10 in [Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md)

In short, you need to add the *white-list, the plugin, and CSP*. ***OR*** SET the version to your compiler.

**NOTE:** If you DO NOT SET the version, you *may* get a set of cascading error. However, maybe, maybe you can add the *white-list* and everything will work as expected. To be clear, after Cordova 4.0.0, you are required to use the `whitelist`.

**OPTIONS:**

1. `<preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.5.0" />` and never use the white list
2. [White List Guide](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-whitelist)

To get a better understanding
READ #6, #7, #10 & #11 of [Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md)